# Ошибка: TypeError at /drinks/

Tags: python, django

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def work(request):
    return request(request, 'work.html')
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp1.views import index
from myapp1.views import about
from myapp1.views import work

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('products/', about),
    path('drinks/', work)
]
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="urf-6">
        <meta name="outhor" content="Magnat">
        <meta name="description" content="Тестовая страница">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
        <title>Главная страница сайт</title>
    </head>
    <body><h1 class="Rizmarket">
        <big>Вас приветствует<br>Rizmarket</big></h1>
        <hr>
        <p style="text-align: center; background-color: #f99100;width: 100cqmax;">
        <em><big>что вы хотите купить у нас есть все что вы хотите</big></em></p>
        <div class="">
        <button class="button" onclick="location.href='products/'">Продукты</button>
        <button class="button" onclick="location.href='drinks/'">Напидки</button>
        <button class="button">Еда</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Bот скрин с ошибкой:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/462ED.jpg

Вот **work.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Rizmarket</a>

                <div class="navbar-wrap">
                    <ul class="navbar-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">О нас </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Цены</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                    </ul>
    
    
                    <a href="#" class="callback">Обратный звонок</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Вот его CSS файл:**

```
body {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #000;
    min-width: 320px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: auto;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.navbar .container{
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all .07s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-menu li a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.callback {
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background-color: coral;
    border-radius: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(255, 127, 80, .2);
    transition: all .1s ease-out;
}

.callback:hover {
    transform: scale(1.04);
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 9px 9px rgba(255, 127, 80, .5);
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    transition: all .07s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
    color: coral;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите, что вы написали во вьюхе work, и сравните с тем, что написано во вьюхах index и about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в функции work вместо render - request

Comment: спосибо большое